# What does "conies about" mean? Hope the quote attached provides enough context

Tags: meaning

"It’s also important that the person should already be outside the house at the stroke of midnight. In Lincolnshire, the first foot should say the following rhyme:
*Take out, and then take in,
Bad luck will begin;
Take in, then take out,
Good luck **conies about**.*
It’s said to be very bad luck to carry fire out of the house on New Year’s Day, or indeed any implement made from iron."

— A treasury of British folklore. Maypoles, Mandrakes & Mistletoe; page 22

Comment: My wild guess is that "good luck", well, "hops around/about like a rabbit".

Comment: _Coney_ is an old word for a rabbit, but I've never heard of it as a verb. My guess is that it's a misprint for **comes about**.

Comment: @KateBunting Indeed it is! And look what I've just looked up in Oxford English Dictionary (should have done so before posting this q of mine tho): 

**II. † ˈcony, coney, v. Obs. rare.
[from the noun]  
intr. To act the rabbit.  
1611 Florio, Coniglieggiare, to cunnie, to play the cunnie, to bee fearefull and lurke in holes.**

Thank you kindly, KateBunting

Comment: I’m closing this question as it was based on a typo

Answer (score 1):

A [[cony](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cony)][1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cony) is an old English word for a rabbit *or something made from rabbit fur*. In many old cultures, rabbits (particularly white rabbits) were seen as promoting good luck. A rabbit's foot was sometimes kept as a good-luck charm. So, a 'good luck cony' (plural, *conies*) could either be a rabbit or such a charm.

The most obvious meaning of "good luck conies" is simply "lucky rabbits", and "about" means that they are 'around' in the sense of you seeing them everywhere around you. This works well in this rhyme, as many old English rhymes and sayings have a line about good fortune and then one about bad (eg *'red sky at night, shepherds delight; red sky in the morning, sailors warning'*). Your rhyme says that one action will lead to bad luck, the other will lead to good-luck rabbits being around you.

Alternatively, 'about' can be an abbreviated way of saying "*about your person*" in the sense of carrying something with you. So, "*good luck conies about*" could be an advisory to keep your good luck charm with you, but that doesn't really work with the structure of the rhyme being that one thing promotes bad luck, the other way promotes good. Having to keep your charm about you would suggest that bad luck needed warding off.